# Play sound every x seconds (loop)

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to loop this sound every 60 seconds. Now it plays just once.

```
<audio id="audio_bell">
  <source src="bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("audio_bell").play();
    }, 60*1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` runs the callback once *after* `<n>` milleseconds, while `setInterval` runs the callback *every* `<n>` milliseconds, so change in this way

```
var audio_bell = document.getElementById("audio_bell");
setInterval(function(){
      audio_bell.play();
}, 60*1000)
```

As a side note, you could cache a reference to the DOM node of your audio element outside the callback function.